# Need to replicate query in spring mongotemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

*I am looking to see if i can replicate this query using spring mongo template.

```
db.getCollection('historical-hourly').aggregate([
{$match: {
    "city": "london",
    "hourlyWeather.time": {
        $gte: 1582779600

      }
    }
    },{ $sort: { "createdDateTime": -1 }},{
    $group: {
    _id:{
    "city": "$city",
    "time": "$hourlyWeather.time"
    },
    'doc': { '$first': '$$ROOT' }
    }
    },
    {
       '$replaceRoot': { 'newRoot':  '$doc' } 
  }])
```

If anyone could lead me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("city").is("london").and("hourlyWeather.time").gte(1582779600)),
    sort(Direction.DESC, "createdDateTime"),
    group(Fields.from(Fields.field("city"), Fields.field("time", "hourlyWeather.time"))).first("$$ROOT").as("doc"),
    replaceRoot("doc")
);

AggregationResults<Document> docs = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "historical-hourly", Document.class);

for(Document doc: docs) {
    System.out.println(doc.toJson());
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you it was just what i was looking for.